# No RequestToken to Authorize

Tags: iphone, soundcloud

I have created an iPhone application with integration of SoundCloudAPI. When I try to run the application I am getting following error message:

```
Error Domain=SoundCloudAPIError Code=2001 "The operation couldn't be
completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error - 1012)" UserInfo=0x13cbc0
{httpErrorStatus=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The
operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error - 1012.)"
UserInfo=0x137b90 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://api.soundcloud.com/
oauth/access_token, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://
api.soundcloud.com/oauth/access_toekn, NSUnderlyingError=0x13b590 "The
operation couldn't be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -
1012.)"}, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn't be completed.
(NSURLErrorDomain error - 1012.)}
```

Any one please tell me how to resolve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem.

Issue is; I did not entered the Callback URL under "Callback URL (OAuth 2 Redirect URI)"

To enter this, follow below steps:

```
1. Go to http://soundcloud.com/you/apps/testapp/edit and click on "Add info for publication to the app gallery".
2. Enter your Callback URL under "Callback URL (OAuth 2 Redirect URI)"
```

Deselect both checkboxes before saving, so your app doesn't get published just yet.